# Unable to update project conf variable in program

Tags: c, contiki, contiki-process

I want to update value of a variable at run time, present in project configuration as per some condition. But currently I am getting this error:
`error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Actual code:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include <stdio.h> /* For printf() */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);

static void update_project_conf_value(void)
{
    printf("Original Value: %d\n",TEST_VALUE);
    TEST_VALUE = 0;
    printf("After update: %d\n",TEST_VALUE);
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
    PROCESS_BEGIN();
    update_project_conf_value();
    PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Project configuration:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_CONF_H_
#define PROJECT_CONF_H_

#define TEST_VALUE 1
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#endif /* PROJECT_CONF_H_ */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

**Note:** I want to update it in one of file as per some condition and then use the updated value in a different file.

Comment: `TEST_VALUE` isn't a variable that can be updated

Comment: See I donno about contiki, but as far as I know about `C`, macros are not updated like that. Macros are preprocessed. `TEST_VALUE` is not a variable. Nothing like `TEST_VALUE` would even exist at run time, it would be replaced by 1 everywhere.

Comment: In case you need macro values based on conditions, you can use `#if`, `#elif` to give that macro a value.

Comment: Thanks @Mihir, Is there any possible way by which I can update its value as per some condition at runtime?

Comment: @SUBHANSHUSAHU , you should understand what macros are at first place. Assume you have a code in which you find a string and just replace it. Thats what is done. At run time TES_VALUE doesn't even exist. The replacement is the first thing to take place, even before compiling.

Comment: Note that if the code that's compiled varies depending on the setting of `TEST_VALUE`, then changing it (by any means) at run time will mean that the program needs to be recompiled too.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `TEST_VALUE` is  a macro. You can read it but you can not write to it. It will also disappear at runtime.

What you really want is a global variable.

In the header put something like this:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_CONF_H_
#define PROJECT_CONF_H_

int g_TEST_VALUE; // Declaration

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#endif /* PROJECT_CONF_H_ */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

in your source put something like this:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include <stdio.h> /* For printf() */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

extern int g_TEST_VALUE = 1; // Definition

PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);

static void update_project_conf_value(void)
{
    printf("Original Value: %d\n",TEST_VALUE);
    g_TEST_VALUE = 0;
    printf("After update: %d\n",TEST_VALUE);
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
    PROCESS_BEGIN();
    update_project_conf_value();
    PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: The global variable is updated for current file but I want the value of variable to be updated in current file and then use the updated value in different file.
I tried with following code:
```int local_variable;

if (a==5)
{local_variable=5;}
else
{local_variable=0;}

extern int global_TEST_VALUE = local_variable;```
But I am getting this error message: ```error: initializer element is not constant```

Comment: @SUBHANSHUSAHU ah, so each other time you use it (except for the one time at the beginning `extern int g_TEST_VALUE = 1` you should use it as `g_TEST_VALUE = local_variable`

Comment: in this case, if I print the value of ```g_TEST_VALUE``` from a different file, the value that is assigned while the definition is displayed i.e.```1``` because of ```extern int g_TEST_VALUE = 1;``` instead of ```0``` that should be because of ```g_TEST_VALUE = local_variable```

Comment: @SUBHANSHUSAHU Indeed that is correct. You get the value depending on the file you compile and run. At this point I'm very unsure what your end goal is.

Comment: Since I have updated the value of ```g_TEST_VALUE``` equal to ```0```  in above code. I want this updated value of ```g_TEST_VALUE``` in different file instead of the definition value

Comment: @SUBHANSHUSAHU That should work then. You first run the code which updates it to 0 followed by the code which uses it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200032/discussion-between-john-and-subhanshu-sahu).